# How to search backwards in emacs shell?

Tags: shell, emacs

I love emacs shells, but there is a confusing thing for people used to use the gnome shell (like me). The backwards search does not work the same way. `C-r` searches in the buffer, not in the command history, and `M-r` searches in the command history but when pressed twice toggles between direct and regexp search, i.e. does not  search for the previous match in the command history. So, how to do that?

**Edit**: The shell I was looking when I wrote this is what you get with `M-x shell`, I didn't know there were other shells in emacs. See e.g. https://plus.google.com/112537550357635435516/posts/Wgpk2mH6hQh

Comment: isearch-backward / search-backward / search-backward-regexp

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Type M-r , search for something, and then press C-r to repeat the same search in the  command history.

Comment: what about navigating foward ? C-p ?

Comment: @zinking C-s is navigating forward.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>M-r</kbd>, then write something, then press <kbd>C-r</kbd> as many times as needed.